# Фильтрация поисковых запросов по наличию запрещённых фраз.

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, коллеги.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше всего организовать блокировку страницы по наличию фраз в поисковом запросе посетителей?
Скрипт обрабатывает большое количество запросов (200-1000 запросов/секунду).

Сейчас это реализовано средствами php с помощью подобной функции:

```
function isNotInBlacklist($query) {
    $blackList = array_flip(file(SYSTEM_DIR.'/blacklist/isset.txt', FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES|FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES));
    if (isset($blackList[$query])) return false;
    $blackListSubstr = file(SYSTEM_DIR.'/blacklist/substr.txt', FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES|FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
    foreach ($blackListSubstr as $currentString) {
        if (mb_substr_count($query, $currentString, 'UTF-8')) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Все запросы на входе функции всегда в нижнем регистре.

Когда в каждом из список было по десятку строк, всё работало нормально, но сейчас список разбух до нескольких тысяч и потребление памяти, как и время генерации html страниц увеличилось.
Если вопрос с памятью можно решить апгрейдом сервера, то скорость генерации станицы хочется оставить минимальной (поисковики это любят).

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно решаются подобные вопросы?
Возможно есть специальный софт, который спроектирован для этого? Или алгоритмы, которые работают быстрее?

Благодарю за ответы.

С уважением.